# Usage of Zuul and Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I'm creating a microservice architecture demo application.

I got a doubt that, do we need both `Zuul` and `API-Gateway`?
What is not possible in `Zuul` and `API-Gateway` so that we need both?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zuul` brings along the capabilities of a gateway (or `API-gateway`). As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_router_and_filter_zuul):

> `Zuul` is a JVM-based router and server-side load balancer from Netflix

It is well integrated in the `sping-boot` cloud project and can be used as router and load balancer. This are the core features of a gateway. Thus I would not double this function and stick to `Zuul` here.

Also I want to point out, that there are a lot of similar `API-gateway` solutions that can be used in the context of a `spring-boot` application. [Here](https://engineering.opsgenie.com/comparing-api-gateway-performances-nginx-vs-zuul-vs-spring-cloud-gateway-vs-linkerd-b2cc59c65369) you can find an article explaining and comparing them. The three products mentioned there are:

- `NGINX`
- `Zuul`
- `Spring Cloud Gateway`